# New to coding, What Am I missing?

Tags: javascript

working on JS, What am I missing? Thank you

Modify the function below to greet only those with an even number of letters in their name

```
function helloYou(name)
 numbers.filter (n => n % 2 =i= 1);{

}

/* Do not modify code below this line */

console.log(helloYou('Bob'), `<-- should return undefined`)
console.log(helloYou('Anna'), `<-- should return "Hello, Anna!"`)
```

Comment: Well, for one thing, you need to move that `{` bracket up to after `function helloYou(name)`. Unless I screwed that up when I formatted it...

Comment: Secondly, you are filtering something called `numbers`, but what is that? It's not defined anywhere.

Comment: Thirdly, I'm not sure what you gain from doing a `filter`. I think what you want is a simple `if(name.length % 2 === 0) { return "blah blah blah"; }`

Answer (score 1):

To access the number of letters in the string, you can use the attribute `.length`.

Then to check if this number is even a modulus 2 should return 0, that's what we need to check. This condition goes in an `if` statement.

Finally, if this condition is met, return `Hello` concatenated with `name`.

Otherwise nothing is returned, so it's `undefined` (there is no need to explicitly write `return undefined`).

```js
function helloYou(name) {
  if (name.length % 2 === 0) {
    return "Hello, " + name;
  }
}

/* Do not modify code below this line */

console.log(helloYou('Bob'), `<-- should return undefined`)
console.log(helloYou('Anna'), `<-- should return "Hello, Anna!"`)
```

Comment: It is best practice to return a value outside of any if statements. This code would throw errors using common linter configurations like airbnb style for example.

Comment: What do you mean return a value outside any if statements ?

Comment: You only return inside the if statement.

Comment: A lot of linters might throw error on code from beginners like that. For space after function name, for backticks for simple string, ... There is nothing to return otherwise (see the first console.log, it's `undefined`), there is no point in returning `undefined` since it's what's returned, `undefined` is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

The variable `numbers` is actually undefined in this case.

Also, [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) is not useful in this situation. Filter is mainly used to get the elements that match a condition from an array.

Your should use an if statement to check for even length. Better yet, you can use the ternary operator. Here is an example:

```js
function helloYou(name) {
  return name.length % 2 === 0 ? 'Hello, ' + name : undefined;
}

console.log(helloYou('Bob'));
console.log(helloYou('Anna'));
```